# Let T be a linear transformation from $P_{2}$ to $ \mathbb{R} ^{3}$. Is T an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T((f(t))=\left[ \begin{matrix} f\left( 1\right) \\ f'\left( 2\right) \\ f\left( 3\right) \end{matrix} \right] $

I get the linearity of the transformation $T$, as $T(f(t)+g(t)) = Tf(t)+Tg(t)$, and $kT(f(t))=Tf(kt)$.

I also get that $dim(P_{2}) = dim(\mathbb{R} ^{3})=3$, so it could be an isomorphism. Apparently is is not an isomorphism, and I am having trouble pinning down why. The answer I have is that it is not an ismomorphism since $T(t^2 -4t+3)=\overrightarrow {0}$. I can't figure out where that comes from. Would someone help me figure that out, please?

Thanks!

Comment: You need only to calculate $f(1), f'(2)$ and $f(3)$ for $f(t) = t^2 - 4t+3$ and see if they are zero.

Comment: @JohnMa, would that be with the a,b,and c coefficients?

Comment: What $a, b, c$ coefficients?

Comment: Where do the $1, 4, 3$ coefficients come from?

Comment: You want to show that $T$ is not an isomorphism, then it suffices to find a nonzero $f$ in $P_2$ so that $T(f) = 0$. Note that $f(t) = (t-1)(t-3)$ is such a candidate as $f(1) = f(3)$ obviously. One then check that $f'(2) = 0$ also in this case, so $T(f) =  \vec 0$.

Comment: Okay I think I get it. These are arbitrary values that happen to generate the zero vector, then?

Comment: Then $T$ is not injective and so it's not an isomorphism!